# JavaScript get all information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to receive information from php, my first parameter is the number of lines it will get, the second one is the name, the third is the socket, all i have now is this :

(**JavaScript code**)

```
    $.ajax({

        url: 'compatibilidades.php',
        data: { 
            socket: $("#board option:selected").attr('value') 
        },
        success: function(dadosRecebidos) {

            for (i = 0; i < dadosRecebidos.substr(0, dadosRecebidos.indexOf('_')) ; i++ ) {
                var selectorID = dadosRecebidos.substr(0, dadosRecebidos.indexOf('-'));
                dadosRecebidos = dadosRecebidos.slice(dadosRecebidos.indexOf('-'),999);

                var nome = dadosRecebidos.substr(1, dadosRecebidos.indexOf('<') - 1);
                dadosRecebidos = dadosRecebidos.slice(dadosRecebidos.indexOf('<'),999);                 

                var socket = dadosRecebidos.substr(1, dadosRecebidos.indexOf('>') - 1);
                dadosRecebidos = dadosRecebidos.slice(dadosRecebidos.indexOf('>'),999);

                console.log(selectorID);
            }               

        }   

    });}}
```

(**php code**)

```
<?php 

$socket = $_GET["socket"];

$bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestao_utilizadores" , "root" , "");

$getComponentes = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM componentes WHERE ( Socket=:socket )");
$getComponentes->bindValue(':socket' , $socket);
$getComponentes->execute();
$resultado = $getComponentes->fetchAll();

For ($i = 0; $i < $getComponentes->rowCount() ; $i++) { 
        echo $getComponentes->rowCount() . "_" . $resultado[$i]["Tipo"] . "-" . $resultado[$i]["Nome"] . "<" . $resultado[$i]["Socket"] . "> "; 
}
```

but it is only printing once

Comment: rowcount doesnot bring the number of rows for a select query. try foreach ($resultado...

Comment: it is receiving, and has the value that is supposed to appear (2)

Comment: Could you show how does an example dadosRecebidos string looks like?

Comment: 2_board-GIGABYTE Z97X-GAMING5<1150>2_cpu-INTEL I7 4790K 4.0GHz<1150>

Answer (score 0):

The PDO::rowCount is guaranteed to work with DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE queries. It may work properly with SELECT on some databases but you shouldn't really rely on this.

The PDO::fetchAll funtion returns an array of rows (or FALSE if there's been an error) so if you need to know the count of rows returned simply use the count($resultado) or add COUNT(*) call in your query. If you don't need to know the exact count but only to perform some operations on each row, the Php foreach function is your friend, as mentioned by @Julio Soares

UPDATE:
It seems I didn't quite understood the problem - anyway, the first part of my answer still stands. Now, addressing the real problem - it looks for me like you're overcomplicating a simple thing. Have you considered using JSON as the data format? It's very straightforward to json_encode an array and later to have it as an js object/array, so you can easily access each column from each row without any hassle.

Comment: the string recebeDados has all the info from php, the objective is to separate the various parts, the parameter of the number is ok, the problem is how to separate those various parts